# M an R-module, where M is a commutative ring, if $M≅R/I$ for some ideal I of R, then $M$ is a cyclic R-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals, cyclic-groups

M is an R-module, where M is a commutative ring, if $M≅R/I$ for some ideal I of R, then show $M$ is a cyclic R-module.

Note: $M$ is a cyclic R-module means $M=<m>$ for some $m\in M$.

Please help, I have not idea how to do this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$R/I$ is generated by the class of $1$. (If $R$ is not unitary, the assertion is false anyway)

Comment: could you explain that in a bit more details? i am not sure what you mean by generated by the class of 1?

Comment: In your notation we have $R/I = \langle \overline 1 \rangle$, where $\overline 1$ denotes the image of $1$ with respect to the canonical projection $R \to R/I$, thus the element $1+I \in R/I$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!